# what is a person who is unusually interested in others' misfortunes

Tags: phrase-requests

What is a phrase for a person who is unusually interested in others' misfortunes and enjoys gossiping about such?

Answer (score 3):

Next to *schadenfreude* which @Hank has proposed in his answer (prior to this edit of mine) and which, in my view deserves the award of correct answer, the nearest strictly English term is probably ***busybody***, defined by the OED as -  *An officious, interfering, meddling, or prying person; one who involves himself or herself in other people's affairs without invitation.*

It doesn't specify that a busybody is necessarily interested in other's *misfortunes* though less than well-disposed motivations are often implied by its use. A good example of a ***busybody*** is the brilliantly enacted character of Susan Carter in the BBC radio soap *The Archers*.

The only problem with *schadenfreude* is that it describes a condition, whilst the OP's request is for the name of such a person.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps ***schadenfreude*** will fit as the word you are looking for:

> #### Schadenfreude
>
> 1. Enjoyment obtained from the troubles of others
> 2. A feeling of enjoyment that comes from seeing or hearing about the troubles of other people

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/schadenfreude))

Answer (score 0):

My choice would be as below:

```
Evil
Satan
```

Example usage is, "Oh boy, he is evil..".

You may to refer such person, idiomatically as "**the evil one**", should you like it, as in "he is the evil one, I was talking about sometime back..".